# VSCode Typescript Angular 2 Debug Error

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a problem on debugging typescript using VSCode. I use angular v2.4.4, typescript v2.1.5, npm v3.10.10, and node v6.9.4.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\app\\main.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

main.js:

```
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
//# sourceMappingURL=c:/workspace/myapp/main.js.map
```

Debug Console:

```
node --debug-brk=10387 --nolazy app\main.js 
Debugger listening on [::]:10387
c:\workspace\myapp\app\main.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

The compilation is done without any error. What should I do to fix this debug error?

I added the following code to give the clearer picture on how my web app works.

system.config.js:

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
        target: "es6",
        module: "commonjs"},
    map: {
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
        'rxjs'    : 'node_modules/rxjs'
    },
    paths: {
        'node_modules/@angular/*': 'node_modules/@angular/*/bundles'
    },
    meta: {
        '@angular/*': {'format': 'cjs'}
    },
    packages: {
        'app'                              : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
        'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx'},
        '@angular/core'                    : {main: 'core.umd.min.js'},
        '@angular/common'                  : {main: 'common.umd.min.js'},
        '@angular/compiler'                : {main: 'compiler.umd.min.js'},
        '@angular/router'                  : {main: 'router.umd.min.js'},
        '@angular/platform-browser'        : {main: 'platform-browser.umd.min.js'},
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js'}
    }
});
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import ApplicationComponent from './components/application/application';
import CarouselComponent from "./components/carousel/carousel";
import FooterComponent from "./components/footer/footer";
import NavbarComponent from "./components/navbar/navbar";
import ProductItemComponent from "./components/product-item/product-item";
import SearchComponent from "./components/search/search";
import StarsComponent from "./components/stars/stars";
import {ProductService} from "./services/product-service";
import HomeComponent from "./components/home/home";
import ProductDetailComponent from "./components/product-detail/product-detail";

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                    RouterModule.forRoot([
                        {path: '',                    component: HomeComponent},
                        {path: 'products/:prodTitle', component: ProductDetailComponent}
    ]) ],
    declarations: [ ApplicationComponent,
                    CarouselComponent,
                    FooterComponent,
                    NavbarComponent,
                    HomeComponent,
                    ProductDetailComponent,
                    ProductItemComponent,
                    SearchComponent,
                    StarsComponent],
    providers:    [ProductService,
                   {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap:    [ ApplicationComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: you are compiling to es 6. and that leaves the import statements in by the looks of it. :) It causes the browser to crash because it doesn't know how ot handle them.

Comment: Toskv,  thank you for your response I appreciate it. I have to compile to es6 because I use the latest version of Typescript 2 and Angular 2. Besides, if I compile to es5, I will have tons of compilation error. This debug error is happening only in VSCode but if I try to run "npm start" from the project root folder, the web app works like a charm, no error at all and I can use the Edge, Firefox, IE or Chrome debug window. But this is not what I am after. I want to use VSCode debug utilities. Please let me know if anybody has used VSCode to debug typescript v2.1.5 and angular 2.4.4 web app.

Comment: I'm not sure how come your project works but the import statement is not listed as supported by most of the the browsers you mentioned https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: I have edited my question to add more codes so you may have a clearer picture about how my project works. I think the import statement is listed according to the added codes above. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: @toskv is right, but also, are you sure you want to be running this in Node? I think you want to run it in a browser instead.

Comment: Can you be more specific here about what is right (the import statement, etc)? If this is the import statement, the snippet code above doesn't have enough import statement? I have been using Visual Studio IDE since VS 97 Codename Boston, so I get used to with F5 and then internet browser. Is there a way we can accomplish the same in VS Code? I don't really care if I have to use node or not in the task.json as long as I can hit F5 then go to the internet browser and use VS Code debug windows.

Comment: I have been waiting for two days to get the answer of my question. Is there anybody with Typescript, Angular 2 and Visual Studio Expert who can help me out on this problem?